# Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.UserDeniedAuthorizationException: Access is denied

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing **Spring Cloud** project and getting the below error when accessing the though client code not sure why I am getting Could not fetch user details: class `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException, Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.`

Could you please guide what is the issue ? Code is taken from the pluralsight and without any customization yet.

```
ron job started
Token: 77f012d4-7258-4314-9cfc-280762421ccb
2018-04-10 13:43:12.634  INFO 9056 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-10 13:43:12.655 ERROR 9056 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at pluralsight.demo.PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecurecliApplication.main(PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecurecliApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.UserDeniedAuthorizationException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:116) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:33) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2913) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorHandler.java:130) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at pluralsight.demo.PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecurecliApplication.run(PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecurecliApplication.java:45) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

**PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecurecliApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecurecliApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PluralsightSpringcloudM4SecurecliApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("cron job started");

        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:9000/services/oauth/token");

        //must be a valid scope or get an error; if empty, get all scopes (default); better to ask for one
        resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("toll_read"));

        //must be valid client id or get an error
        resourceDetails.setClientId("pluralsight");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("pluralsightsecret");

        //diff user results in diff authorities/roles coming out; preauth on roles fails for adam, works for barry
        resourceDetails.setUsername("agoldberg");
        resourceDetails.setPassword("pass1");

        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
        //could also get scopes: template.getAccessToken().getScope()
        String token =  template.getAccessToken().toString();//.getValue();

        System.out.println("Token: " + token);

        String s = template.getForObject("http://localhost:9001/services/tolldata", String.class);

        System.out.println("Result: " + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the logs it seems that you get the Token, but when you are trying to get the resource you are getting exception: UserDeniedAuthorizationException. If this is the case, it seems obivious to me as you are not passing the token in the request.

Comment: No, I am passing the token in the request, still the issue is same

Comment: The exception is in this line right???  "String s = template.getForObject("http://localhost:9001/services/tolldata", String.class);"